# django: m2m field may not be empty

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Students can be assigned to many groups.

- One student can be assigned to many groups
- One Group can hold many students.

With code below I can

- create Student with no group or assigned to some groups.
- I can change everything with success, exept...

Exept that **I can not remove all groups assigned to student.**
I assume that some student can unsubscribe from all groups.
But django don't like that and throw **error**:

`{'groups': [ErrorDetail(string='This list may not be empty.', code='empty')]}`

Code:

Models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
 
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group)
```

Create Student:

```
new_student = Student.objects.create(
    first_name = request.data["first_name"],
    last_name = request.data["last_name"],
    )

groups_id = request.data["group_id"]

if(groups_id):
    for group_id in groups_id:
        new_student.groups.add(group_id)
```

Change Student:

```
def change_student(request, id):
 
    student_to_change = Student.objects.get(id=id)
 
    serializer = StudentSerializer(
        instance=student_to_change,
        data={
            'first_name': request.data["first_name"],
            'last_name': request.data["last_name"],
            'groups': request.data["groups"],
            }
        )
 
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
```

And when I try to execute change_student with for example:
request.data :

```
{'id': 16, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'groups': []}
```

I get

```
{'groups': [ErrorDetail(string='This list may not be empty.', code='empty')]}
```

error

And serializers:

```
class GroupSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = '__all__'

class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: I added my answer. But I want to change the code in the views too, so could you please add the whole content of the views.py file here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that the problem was with models.
There should be "blank=True" inside Student class and now when creating student object - groups field can be send as empty list

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set two fields for reading and writing `groups` attribute.

```
class StudentSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    groups = GroupSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)
    group_ids = serializers.ListField(
        child = serializers.IntegerField(), write_only = True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['group_ids']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        group_ids = validated_data.pop('group_ids')
        student = Student.objects.create(**validated_data)
        student.groups.set(group_ids)
        return student

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        group_ids = validated_data.pop('group_ids')
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.groups.set(group_ids)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

And the payload should be like:

```
{'id': 16, 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'group_ids': []}
```

I added the code for `groups` field in the serializer. So you don't need to write the logic to save that field in the views.